# how to get the list items from sharepoint using perl script

Tags: perl, sharepoint-2010

I am try to get the list items from share point server site using perl

script.i am write the script but give the error "401 Unauthorized". please help to solve

this problem.In this i am geven domain ,username ,password also.once see the credentials.

i am write script below

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
 use LWP::Debug;
 use Data::Dumper;
use SOAP::Lite on_action => sub { "$_[0]$_[1]"; };
 import SOAP::Data 'name', 'value';
 our $sp_endpoint = 'http://sezdsk22787/_vti_bin/lists.asmx';
 our $sp_domain = 'dev:80';
 our $sp_username = 'spadmin';
 our $sp_password = 'Cmc@1234';
 $debug = 0;
  if ($debug) {
      LWP::Debug::level('+');
   SOAP::Lite->import(+trace => 'all');
 }
 my @ua_args = (keep_alive => 1);
my @credentials = ($sp_domain, "", $sp_username, $sp_password);
 my $schema_ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(@ua_args);
  $schema_ua->credentials(@credentials);
 $soap = SOAP::Lite->proxy($sp_endpoint, @ua_args, credentials => \@credentials);
 $soap->schema->useragent($schema_ua);
 $soap->uri("http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetVersions");

  $lists = $soap->GetListCollection();
 quit(1, $lists->faultstring()) if defined $lists->fault();
  sub lists_getid
  {
  my $title = shift;
  my @result = $lists->dataof('//GetListCollectionResult/Lists/DL_Accounts');
   foreach my $data (@result) {
   my $attr = $data->attr;
         return $attr->{ID} if ($attr->{Title} eq $title);
    }
     return undef;
 }
print "@credentials \n";
 sub lists_getitems
 {
     my $listid = shift;
     my $in_listName = name('listName' => $listid);
     my $in_viewName = name('viewName' => '');
    my $in_rowLimit = name('rowLimit' => 99999);
     my $call = $soap->GetListItems($in_listName, $in_viewName, $in_rowLimit);
     quit(1, $call->faultstring()) if defined $call->fault();
     return $call->dataof('//GetListItemsResult/listitems/data/row');
 }

 my $list_id = lists_getid('Disk Space');
 print "List ID is: $list_id\n";
 my @items = lists_getitems($list_id);
 foreach my $data (@items) {
    my $attr = $data->attr;
    print Dumper($attr);
}
```